# How can I find out in which directories Firefox looks for plugins?

Tags: firefox, plugins

From [MozillaZine](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Determining_plugin_directory_on_Linux), I learned that Firefox seems to use a different set of directories where it looks for plugins on different OSes.

This is quite annoying, as one always has to think first where to install a new plugin when working with different OSes. Note that I do **not** want to install it into my homedir, as I want other users of the same machine to be able to use the plugin as well.

Is there any simple way to find out in which directories firefox looks for plugins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also, please see [Plug-in_Detection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Gecko_Plugin_API_Reference/Plug-in_Basics#Plug-in_Detection)

Answer (score 0):

FireFox plugins / addons are located within the profile folder you are currently using.

See [this](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder_-_Firefox) link to where the profile folders are located under various operating systems. In the profile, there is another folder called 'Extensions' which stores the plugins / addons.

If you want multiple users to use the same profile, and therefore load the same plugins - see [this](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profiles.ini_file)  link to edit the Profile.ini file and choose a specific profile for FireFox to load.

Comment: This is almost precisely the answer that I was _not_ looking for. I was not asking for a place to store the plugins, but how to find out where Firefox expects the plugin. One of these places is the Homedir/Profile, but under *nix, it is not usually accessible by other users, and in particular it will not be searched when other users start firefox. Using a profile that is shared between different users furthermore has the problem, that besides the plugins, the users will share all settings, bookmarks, passwords etc.

Comment: Calm yourself Harold.